# Flutter IOS cannot run app in release mode on real device

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, dart

Hello everybody I implemented an app using Flutter 3.10 and it works fine in the ios simulator and then I deployed the .ipa file to testflight to be tested,but when opening the public link of testflight the app shows white screen and doesn't open.I try to run the app in release mode on a real device instead of simulator :

```
    >flutter run --release
```

but it gives this error:

[image]

despite I :
1-set the Development team.
2-have a valid unique Bundle ID
3-the real device is registered with my Apple Developer Account
4-I checked "automatically provision profile" in xcode.

5-I inserted these line in the podfile but with no success:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so I can't figure out the problem
I appreciated your help

Flutter : 3.10.

xcode :14.2 (14C18)

Macos : 12.5 Macbook Air (M1 2020)

Flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-EG)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Error: Failed to prepare the device for development. Please unlock and reconnect the device. (code 806)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```